# Improving WPF performance by breaking up the UI into 'regions' - is this possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I've run a very simple performance test on a WPF client app:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> data = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    public ObservableCollection<int> DataObj { get { return data; } }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(5);
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { data.Add(1); })); //updates the count
                        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.AppendText("1"); })); //updates the string data
                    }
                });

            t.Start();
        }
    }
```

I then have two controls in the UI: a `TextBlock` and a `RichTextBox`.

The `TextBlock` is bound to the `Count` property of the datasource, whilst the `RichTextBox` appends each new data value to its text string (ie. displays the content of the data).

If I disable the `RichTextBox` binding, the `TextBlock` updates very quickly, cycling through the count. However, enabling the `RichTextBox` binding slows *everything* down, both controls update in "globs", maybe once or twice per second. In otherwords the entire UI runs at the pace of the `RichTextBox` binding.

Is there a way to break this performance dependency? I understand the RichTextBox may well be slow, but why does it have to slow down the otherwise lightening fast TextBlock?

Comment: Hey, a performance test case. Looks like that isn't an extinct species yet.

Comment: What happens if you disable the TextBlock binding?

Comment: The RichTextBox still updates at about 2 FPS. I think I need multiple Dispatcher threads, but I haven't found any way to compose a single UI from multiple panes / windows.

Comment: I know the workaround: `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.AppendText("1"); }), DispatcherPriority.Background);`. I haven't understood the problem exactly, but this code is any quicker then the call with normal priority.

Comment: vorrtex - that's a good start. a definite improvement, but it does feel like a workaround. What we really need is a way to define elements in the tree that have their own `Dispatcher` threads, in effect a multi-threaded UI. I've found similar code for displaying videos in UI but nothing that deals with the issue above..

Comment: @flesh what happens if you set in the RichTextBox's binding `IsAsync=True`

Comment: Markus - I'm not actually binding to the RichTextBox, I'm calling `AppendText()`. Setting `IsAsynch=True` for the `TextBlock` causes it to flicker though. Is there a better way to populate the `RichTextBox`?

Answer (score 7):

The specific of WPF is that there is only one UI thread per window.

Although it is possible to use other window and make it look as if it is part of the current application (set the WindowStyle property to None and update position and size), it doesn't look natural and there is better way to sort out performance issues.

As is known, it is necessary to use the `Dispatcher` class to update the UI from a background thread. The `BeginInvoke` method has the optional parameter of the [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) type which have the following values.

1. SystemIdle
2. ApplicationIdle
3. ContextIdle
4. Background
5. Input
6. Loaded
7. Render
8. DataBind
9. Normal
10. Send

The default value is `Normal (9)`, it is almost the highest priority and it is implicitly applied whenever you call the `BeginInvoke` method without parameters. The call to the `RichTextBox` in your example has this priority.

But your `TextBlock` which is bound to the property and isn't updated manually, has the lower priority `DataBind (8)`, that's why it is updated slower.

To make binding quicker, you can reduce the priority of the call to the `RichTextBox` and set a value lower than 8, for example `Render (7)`.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(/*...*/, DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

It will help with the binding, but the UI will not respond on mouse clicks, you will not be able even to close the window.

Continue to reduce the priority:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(/*...*/, DispatcherPriority.Input);
```

The application responds better, but it is still impossible to type something in the `RichTextBox` while it is populated by text.

Therefore the final value is `Background (4)`:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { richTextBox1.AppendText("1"); }),
                  DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Comment: Thanks. You don't have to use `BeginInvoke` to see the improvement (in fact, when you do the two updates run completely out of synch with each other - the TextBlock finishes long before the `RichTextBox`). I'm guessing that the Dispatcher cannot process the items in its queue fast enough when using `Invoke` allowing a higher priority item to be added before it can process the update to `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Also, I'm not entirely clear why we need `DispatcherPriority.Background` and not just some priority that is lower than the `TextBlock` update? Surely all that matters is their relative priorities? Or are there other events in the Dispatcher queue that I'm not taking into account?

Comment: @flesh I use `BeginInvoke` because this call doesn't wait for completion of operation.  The `Background` priority causes the least number of problems. As I've written in the answer, you can use the `Render` priority which is one number less than `DataBinding`, but if you try to click somewhere it won't work because mouse events have lower priority. You can try to set the `Input` priority and then type something in the `RichTextBox` while it is being filled by text. After that return to the `Background` priority and try to type something again. You will see difference.